# i want to run method after requestaccesstoentitytype alertview generates

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

generally to access the ios calendar app in iphone we call the selector `requestAccessToEntityType:completion:`
then an alert will be generated like [this](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2chs1mx.jpg)

so after i press **OK** buttonindex i want to run a method

generally to do that i know that we use `clickedButtonAtIndex` method
but what is this alertview called?

any help is appreciable.....

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i have updated my question.pls refer it once @DavidPostill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to ur above comment, i think u are only requesting access to the calendar. u also have to request authorization from calendar app.
i hope this url may help you[Clickhere](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html)

Comment: thanks for ur help. i m not using `authorizationForEntityType:` it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any access to apples AlertViews because they are likely to be out of the control of your view hierarchy!

However in most cases you can handle almost the same behaviour by implementing the completion handler. Here is a simple example of how this could look like:

```
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //show error
        });
        return;
    }
    if(!granted) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //show not possible without access
    }
    if(!error && granted) {
        accessGrantedBlock();
    }
}];
```

Comment: i want to create a calendar in ios calendar app after getting access to calendar settings. but when the access is granted at first it is not creating the calendar. after restarting the app again it is then creating the new calendar. so i want to create the calendar after i press OK button in the apple alert. help me on this